# Glass text on bottle

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I want to create a text on the glass bottle like this:

[image]

I wrote my text, converted it to Mesh and added some modifier:

1. *Solidify*
2. *Simple Deform*
3. *Shrinkwrap*

But my text won't get out of the bottle. Also my *Solidify* mod looks flat.
[image]

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The order of the modifiers matters: Put the *Simple Deform* at the top of the stack, then the *Shrinkwrap*, and at last the *Solidify*